# PHP exec and OSASCRIPT?

Tags: php, apache, exec, osascript

I have a little Apple script as follow:

```
beep
delay 2
tell application "Finder" to activate
```

It just makes a sound, wait 2 second and then bring the "Finder" window to the foreground.

When I run it from the command line, it works fine.

Then I want PHP to call that script using the exec() php function.

```
<?
$cmd = "/usr/bin/osascript \"myscript.scpt\"";
exec($cmd);
?>
```

It still works fine.

But when I call that same PHP script from the browser, it doesn't work! The PHP starts, the Apple script starts as well since I can hear the beep sound but its last line is not executed.

I thought that would be an environment variable thing so I made sure they were all the same way as in the terminal:

```
$cmd = "HOME='/Users/mikael' && … && /usr/bin/osascript \"myscript.scpt\"";
```

The variables are set properly (as check with env|sort) but still no luck with running my apple script inside a php script displayed in the browser and using the standard MacOS apache stuff.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `osascript` runs from PHP, through the web server, it's not running with a login context, so it can't send Apple events to applications running on the desktop (like the Finder). You'll find that a similar issue arises if you try to use `osascript` over SSH.

Login contexts are a complex, poorly documented area of OS X. You may want to get your hands on a copy of Amit Singh's [*Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach*](http://books.google.com/books?id=K8vUkpOXhN4C&pg=PA1066) if you want to learn more about them.

If you don't, though, the answer is generally pretty simple: don't depend on `osascript` working correctly from the web server.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know there was something called Login contexts in macOS, will check it out. What do you think of the workaround I mentioned below?

Comment: It's not a very good workaround. It's basically depending on the fact that the MAMP launcher runs with a login context; as such, it'll be difficult to get to work reliably in production.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I may have found a way that allows the Apple script to be called from PHP from within a browser.

It is not fully satisfactory but this is what I'm going to do:

So basically instead of using the default macOS apache server, I use this one that sets up a web server & also MySQL: http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

I mention MAMP but there may be other.

my Apple script is finally run fully using that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble and realised that apache executes as user www. 
You can change this by editing etc/apache2/httpd.conf . Change user to your user short name and group to staff.